# Using onChange to update table row count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to I add an onChange event to the following, so that the table rows get counted each time the number of rows updates.

I have checkboxes that are used to show/hide rows, and I need to count the rows each time a user changes the checkbox options.

Sorry I am new to JavaScript.

```js
document.getElementById('rowscount').innerHTML = $('tr:visible').length-1

    function MortgageTypeCheckbox(row){
    var bHide = true;
    $('#type input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
        var chkValue = $(this).val();
        console.log(chkValue);
        if($(row).find('td.'+chkValue).length){
            bHide = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    
    return bHide;
}
function FeeCheckbox(row){
    var bHide = true;
    $('#fee input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
        var chkValue = $(this).val();
        console.log(chkValue);
        if($(row).find('td.'+chkValue).length){
            bHide = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    
    return bHide;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <section id="type">

      <p id="Mortgage Type">Mortgage Type</p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t2" id="t2" checked/>2yr Fixed<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t3" id="t3" checked/>3yr Fixed<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t5" id="t5" checked/>5yr Fixed<br>

    </section>
 
    <section id="fee">

    <p id="Fee">Fee</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="fee" id="fee" checked/>Fee<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="nofee" id="nofee" checked/>No Fee<br>

    </section>

    <p id="rowscount"></p>

        <table>

          <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
          </tr>

        </table>
```

Comment: I didn't want to add all my code. Plus will be using various inputs to filter table rows, not just checkboxes.

Comment: @J.Ayo is there any way ... so we can help you ???

Comment: @J.Ayo you need to create a minimal example that reproduces the bug. I'm not sure why you are reluctanct to add code that will reproduce behavior?

Comment: I am not, I just have a lot of code, and I just wanted to know the basics of how to add onChange as I am new to JavaScript. One second I will add checkbox code

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<p id="rowscount"></p>
<br>

    <table id="test">

      <tr class="visible">
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="visible">
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
      </tr>
<tr class="">
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
     var count = 0;
     $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {  
         count = 0;
          $("#test tr").each(function(){
                if($(this).hasClass("visible"))
                {
                 count = count +1;

                }
            });           
            document.getElementById('rowscount').innerHTML = count;    
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ogyguLv2) . Sample code as you just want how onChange will work...and yes code is in jquery. You can refer the code and tweak it as per your need...